# How does this code work with reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header'

export const CoreLayout = ({ children }) => (
   <div>test</test>
)

CoreLayout.propTypes = {

}

export default CoreLayout
```

But I don't understand how this is picking that is react. I'm used to:

```
import React from 'react';
const Contacts = React.createClass({
   render() {
     return (
       <div></div>
    );
   }
});
export default Contacts;
```

or

```
import React from 'react';
class Contacts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}
export default Contacts;
```

How can I add functions in the coded I showed above? Like functions to add logic in the template an things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const CoreLayout = ({ children }) => (
   <div>test</test>
)
```

Here, `CoreLayout` is called a **Functional Stateless component**.

In the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) about components, the first example you see is a Functional stateless component.

Stateless components can be defined like this:

```
function Welcome(props, context) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

OR using Arrow Function

```
const Welcome = (props, context) => {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

They have the following features:

- They are pure functions. (with first argument `props` and second `context`)
- No Class Needed
- No [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) Keyword
- No state and lifecycle methods.
- Easy to Understand
- Above all, they are simple and elegant.

Comment: Hi free-soul, thanks for the super detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options if you want to break stateless components down.

The first is to break each piece of logic out into a separate stateless component.

```
export const CoreLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <ConditionalHeader showing={true} />
  </div>
)

export const ConditionalHeader = ({ showing }) => (
  showing ? <Header /> : null
)
```

Alternatively, you can define helpers functions inside your component.

```
export const CoreLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const renderHeader = () => showing ? <Header /> : null

  return (
    <div>
      {renderHeader()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Dan Prince. I gave the right answer to free-soul even though you both deserve it as you both are answering 2 different part of my questions, but he did before. Much appreciated in any case.